# JavaScript- searching element withing an object

Tags: javascript

Say I have a `ul` with the class name 'images' cotaining various `li` objects. I have the list pointed by a JS variable using

```
var list = document.GetElementsByClassName("images")[0]; //single 'images' exist in document
```

How do I search all `li` elements within the list pointed by `var list`? Searching on the Internet gave this-

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("images")[0];
var list = *!*element.*/!*getElementsByTagName("li"); // getting syntax error at this line
```

Is there a way to do this without jQuery?

Comment: [`var els = document.querySelectorAll('.images li');`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll)

Comment: `list.getElementsByTagName('li')` should just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

When accessing DOM nodes you can use the now very common `querySelectorAll`.

Given an assumed html structure of:

```
<ul class="images">
  <li>Bob Thorton</li>
  <li>Joe Biden</li>
  <li>Tom <strong>Yorke</strong></li>
</ul>
```

You're JavaScript would be:

```
// Query for the item
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.images li strong');

// Do what you need to do
// Note that items is an array so we access the first result [0]
items[0].style.color = '#f00';
```

Note that `querySelectorAll` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which similar to an array. In the above example we treat the list as an array and only fetch the first DOM Element to color red.

### Demo

Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/sinex/1/edit).